# highlighting current section on scroll - gap between sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with different sections that can be scrolled to or accessed by clicking the corresponding link in the navbar. A demo of the page is on codepen http://codepen.io/meek/pen/NNprYb?editors=1010

I am using the following code to keep track of which section the user is scrolling over and highlighting it in the navbar

```
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {

        var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('.nav li a').each(function() {
            var sectionLink = $(this);
            var section = $(sectionLink.attr('href'));
            if(section.position().top <= currentPos && section.position().top + section.height() > currentPos) {
                $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                sectionLink.parent().addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                sectionLink.parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
```

It works fine, but there is a gap where scrolling through between home and about sections, none of the links are highlighted. I have a feeling this might be because of the space the navbar occupies between home and about, but I'm not sure how to overcome this. Ideally, I'd like to have that gap also highlight "about".

I've tried to add this to the above code:

```
            else if($('#nav-wrapper').position().top <= currentPos && $('#nav-wrapper').position().top + $('#nav-wrapper').height() > currentPos) {
                $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                $('#temp').addClass('active');
            }
```

but it doesn't work. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
Adjust your `if` statement in your `scroll` event to match the following.

```
if(section.position().top <= currentPos && sectionLink.offset().top + section.height() > currentPos)
```

The *key* being, the second instance of `section.position().top` changes to `sectionLink.offset().top`